# Python programatically opening a link by clicking?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, urllib2

**I am trying to parse a whole website**

> Target Link: http://targetsite.com

which has lots of child links and I want to parse all its child links.

> Links within the Target Page:-
>
> http://targetsite.com/childpage/1
>
> http://targetsite.com/childpage/2
>
> http://targetsite.com/childpage/3

The problem I am having is that if I am directly opening these links for example -

> http://targetsite.com/childpage/1

using either **Curl** or **Python urllib2** or **Python Selenium**.

Then the website is **redirecting me to CAPTCHA Page first to Prevent Automated Malicious Programs** from parsing that page.

**But if I open that link by click it in then its Opens without redirecting to CAPTCHA page.**

> Opening http://targetsite.com/childpage/1
>
> By clicking this link from http://targetsite.com main page.

And then it displays that page.

1. I want to know how the website is **tracking** whether a link has been
   opened directly or by click action.
2. **Suggest a suitable way** to do this kind of Web Scraping      automatically in Python

**NOTE**:-
I have also tried it by just copy pasting that link to browser and opening  it directly without using click action in that case too its redirecting  to CAPTCHA Page.

Comment: It is probably looking at your user agent for starters. Next, you can use the browser to figure out what request headers are actually being used and compare the request your automation is making with the real request.

Comment: @merlin2011 Its not looking for user agent . I have tried it by just copy pasting that link to browser  and it then redirects to CAPTCHA. Only time its not redirecting is when I am opening that page by clicking that link from main page

Comment: In that case, perhaps you need to always first request the main page and then request the target page.

Comment: @merlin2011 Yes seems possible only by selenium since I have to retain the main page and open child links in new tab. Any Idea how to do it?

Comment: That's a bit broad. I'd recommend reading over the selenium documentation, trying to write it and then updating your question once you run into any problems.

Comment: @merlin but how browser is tracking whether page has been opened either directly or by clicking?

Comment: The browser doesn't necessarily track it except in so far as cookie or local storage state is updated. It's possible that the server has some heuristic for detecting whether the main page was loaded first.

Comment: I'm guessing child pages need referrer header, check your headers and see if referrer header exists and the value is equal with main link, and tell me the results, or you can include headers in your question(if that's not a problem)

Comment: @Mohammadhzp Yeah its working. It was using referal header to track click  and now it very easily to parse. Thnx a lot for pointing this out.